# Uploading from Google Drive to BOX through AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, box-api, urlfetch

Currently working on a google sheet and implementing a script that will upload a file from Drive to BOX .
I got the authentication down (I am able to get the folder list through the script connecting to the API) but when I get to the uploading part, I am getting an empty request and the file is not getting uploaded to the target folder

My script below:

```
function uploadFile() {

  var boundary = "test";
  var blob = DriveApp.getFileById('<I got my file ID here>').getBlob();
  var service = getService();

  var attributes = "{\"name\":\"test document.pdf\", \"parent\":{\"id\":\"<I got my folder ID here>\"}}";

  var requestBody = Utilities.newBlob(
    "--"+boundary+"\r\n"
    + "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"attributes\"\r\n\r\n"
    + attributes+"\r\n"+"--"+boundary+"\r\n"
    + "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\""+blob.getName()+"\"\r\n"
  + "Content-Type: " + blob.getContentType()+"\r\n\r\n").getBytes()
  .concat(blob.getBytes())
  .concat(Utilities.newBlob("\r\n--"+boundary+"--\r\n").getBytes());

  var options = {
    method: "post",
    contentType: "multipart/form-data; boundary="+boundary,
    payload: requestBody,
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()}
  };

  var request = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content", options);

  Logger.log(request.getContentText()); // empty response

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- When I check the official document of "Upload file" of the BOX API, I found the following curl sample. [Ref](https://developer.box.com/reference/post-files-content/)

  ```
    $ curl -i -X POST "https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content" \
         -H "Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>" \
         -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" \
         -F attributes="{"name":"Contract.pdf", "parent":{"id":"11446498"}}" \
         -F file=@<FILE_NAME>
  ```
- When the request of `multipart/form-data` is run, it seems that at Google Apps Script, the content type is automatically created including the boundary.

When above curl command is converted to Google Apps Script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function uploadFile() {
  var blob = DriveApp.getFileById('<I got my file ID here>').getBlob();
  var service = getService();
  var attributes = {"name":"test document.pdf", "parent":{"id":"<I got my folder ID here>"}};
  var requestBody = {attributes: Utilities.newBlob(JSON.stringify(attributes), "application/json"), file: blob};
  var options = {
    method: "post",
    payload: requestBody,
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()}
  };
  var request = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content", options);
  Logger.log(request.getContentText());
}
```

#### Note:

- In this sample script, it supposes that your access token of `service.getAccessToken()` can be used for uploading the file using the API. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [Upload file of BOX API](https://developer.box.com/reference/post-files-content/)
- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)